# What does this vector function notation mean?

Tags: vectors, definition, random-functions

Under "Functions of Random Vectors: The Method of Transformations"
https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_5_random_vectors.php

The notation says let $G:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ be a continuous invertible function with inverse $H = G ^{-1}$.  Let $Y = G(X)$  where $X$ is a random vector say $[X_1, X_2]^T$.  It then says $X = [X_1, X_2]^T = [H_1(Y_1, Y_2), H_2(Y_1, Y_2)]^T$.

What are $H_1, H_2$ and what is $G(X)$ symbolically?
If $X = [X_1, X_2]^T$ and $Y=[Y_1, Y_2]^T, $$\space$ is $Y=G(X) = [G(X_1), G(X_2)]?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing $X = [X_1, X_2]^T$ you are limiting the discussion to $n = 2$, so I'll keep that way.

As they said, $H$ is the inverse of $G$. It is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which can be written as $H = [H_1, H_2]^T$ with the understanding that $H(Y) = [H_1(Y), H_2(Y)]^T = [H_1(Y_1, Y_2), H_2(Y_1, Y_2)]^T$ for all $(Y_1, Y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, $H_1, H_2$ are the component functions of $H$.

$G(X)$ is a notation for the composite function $G \circ X$.

For your last question, it follows direct from the definitions that $G(X) = [G_1(X), G_2(X)]^T = [G_1(X_1,X_2), G_2(X_1,X_2)]^T$. There is no reason to consider $G(X_1)$ since $G$ take two coordinates as input, not just one.